# Difference in performance of my Dolphin Emulator on Windows and Mac

Tags: macos, emulation, performance, dolphin-emulator

I had a few problems running Pokémon XD: Gale of Darkness on my Mac as it crashes. So I downloaded Windows Vista home premium via bootcamp - but the game lags.

All my settings are the same as on my Mac Dolphin Emulator, and I have had no problems playing any other games on my Mac emulator.

**What could be causing the lag on my Windows Dolphin Emulator?**
*Pokémon XD runs fine on my mac emulator (speed wise) when I use a previously saved file but will then crash (mac specific issue)*

Comment: Windows takes up a rather massive amount of memory, especially anything after XP.  If you have the bare minimums to run Vista, nothing will run very well.

Comment: PROTIP: use proper capitalization, punctuation and break your text into separate paragraphs. If you don't put effort into making your question easy to understand, most of us won't be motivated to put the effort into answering it.

Comment: Hello, block o' text! Goodbye, block o' text!

Comment: Vista is one of the worst Windows versions to use - try 7 or XP instead. Anyway, try a [Linux build](http://code.google.com/p/dolphin-emu/wiki/Linux_Build) instead

Comment: @closevoters: What does this question have to do with illegal/unreleased content?

Comment: @Zommuter well, emulation is a grey area, and the way it was phrased strongly suggests the version of windows is illegitimate (where would you buy a copy of vista nowadays?)

Comment: @TZHX I'm no mac, but the existence of [these](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5634) [articles](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/05/28/using-boot-camp-to-install-vista-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/) does not imply anything illegal. We should assume OP simply had their Vista license from an older PC lying around

Comment: @Zommuter I'm pretty sure TZHX is referring to `So I downloaded [...]` There *are* legal versions of Windows available for download nowadays, though. MSDNAA comes to mind.

Comment: Remember, people.  We try to assume good faith unless we've been actually told it's been pirated.  Since there are valid methods of downloading Vista, let's assume he's legit, shall we?  If anything, we should be closing because he hasn't provided enough information on his computer for us to help at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that can impact the performance of your computer under Boot Camp.

- Make sure Boot Camp and it's drivers are up to date. In Mac OS X, you can go to `Apple Menu > Software Update…` to update your Mac. There should also be a Boot Camp manager in Windows you can use to see if your drivers are up to date on that end.
- Make sure you have the video card drivers up to date. Many Mac models come with **2 video cards standard**, one is a low-end Intel integrated graphics for everyday use and the other is a high-end card for scientific applications, gaming, video/graphics editing and programs where the programmer does't realize they are using a GPU filter instead of a CPU filter. Dolphin may be trying to use the lower end emulator.
- Make sure Windows is using all of your RAM. Check the properties of My Computer to see if Windows has all the RAM installed on your machine.
- Finally, this is probably the most important check you can make: Is your Mac a 64 or 32-bit machine? If you have a 64-bit Mac but are running 32-bit Windows you can end up taking a very large performance hit. Ensuring that you are using 64-bit Windows *and* a 64-bit build of Dolphin on a 64-bit Mac should help with the performance.